# Are there performance benefits to sending a JSON object with Content-Type application/json over JSON.parsing a text/plain string?

Tags: node.js, express

My project at work is posting JSON data to the server. We were using application/json as the Content-Type, but it was causing two requests to be made with each call -- one with OPTIONS and another to actually post the data. Google-fu and Stackoverflow found that this is due to the application/json Content-Type. Switching it to text/plain and JSON.parse()ing it on the server removed this second OPTIONS request, allowing it to post with only a single connection.

As much as this resolved the issue, a back end developer mentioned that he wants to create better configuration for the server so that the OPTIONS request only sends once, then caches for all subsequent requests. I'm not opposed to this, but his reasoning was that doing the JSON.parse for all requests is too much server overhead when it could just be receiving the JSON object in the first place.

I don't know much to anything about the technicalities of Node or networking, but I was under the impression that no matter what Content-Type you sent, the server was always receiving a string, then converting it to that content type once received. That is to say that if you post data with an application/json Content-Type, the server is *still* running JSON.parse to actually convert it to a JSON object.

Am I wrong? Is there a speed (or any other) performance benefit to posting data with the application/json Content-Type? I can appreciate the fact that it labels submitted data accurately, but I am mostly curious as to if my conceptualization of how the server receives data is wrong. Again, I'm under the impression that receiving a string and JSON.parse'ing it is exactly what is happening when you post with an application/json Content-Type.

Any insight into the inner workings here would be appreciated.